# Append element after another without a container

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML strings that can be something like:

Any HTML5 tag like

```
<header>
    Stuff inside element
</header>
```

or

```
Text before the footer
<footer>
    Stuff inside element
</footer>
```

or simply

```
This is the content of the string
```

I would like to append one of them after an existing element in a case like this:

```
<div>
    Existing element
</div>
[ i should put loaded HTML string right here ]
```

I'm not very skilled on writing plain JavaScript and I don't know a way to append the string without create a container element to be appended like this:

```
var newElement = document.createElement("div");
newElement.innerHTML = "<header>Stuff inside element</header>";
existingElement.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, existingElement.nextSibling);
```

My problem is this code generates this portion of HTML:

```
<div>
    Existing element
</div>
<div> <-- unwanted container
    <header>
        Stuff inside element
    </header>
</div> <-- unwanted container
```

How can I avoid creating the container element to put the HTML string inside the document when I don't have always the same content to be put inside it?

Comment: try using unwrap in jquery. For ex after your code add this line as well newElement.unwrap("div");   .. This will remove the unwanted container.

Comment: @Yunus: Or, instead of fixing the result, fix what's causing the problem -.- Besides, this question isn't tagged with jQuery, nor uses jQuery anywhere.

Comment: @Cerbrus thanks for this comment "instead of fixing the result, fix what's causing the problem".. I will remember this.. :)

Comment: Does exists a way to avoid using `document.createElement("div")`? Because for what I know, with `createElement` I can't put just text inside the HTML which should be updated, and in the other cases I'm forced to parse the string, find the node type, remove it from the string and create it dynamically, not very useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with this:

```
existingElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin", htmlString);
```

This will let me to avoid the creation af an element container.

Answer (score 0):

It's really quite simple:

```
var newElement = document.createElement("header");
newElement.innerHTML = "Stuff inside element";
existingElement.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, existingElement.nextSibling);
```

Comment: question says the outer tags are in the string. Also doesn't work for the case where there's no outer element in the string (second and third examples)

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but wouldn't the following work:

```
var newElement = document.createElement("header");
newElement.innerHTML = "Stuff inside element";
existingElement.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, existingElement.nextSibling);
```

Comment: question says the outer tags are in the string. Also doesn't work for the case where there's no outer element in the string (second and third examples)